# Vim: For Multiple Files: Copy all Text, Replace and Paste

Tags: vim

I want to do the following for multiple files using Vim:

1. Copy all text in each file
2. Replace some text
3. Paste the copied text at the end of the each file
4. Replace some other text

Here are my commands for one file:

```
:%y
:%s/old1/new1/g
:G
:P
:%s/old2/new2/g
```

Can anybody tell me the syntax to do so? Especially that I'm new to Vim!

I found out that argdo can execute commands on multiple files. I found many examples to use argdo in replacing text, but I couldn't find the syntax to use argdo with :%y, :G, or :P

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @ib mentioned, I'd do this with ex commands<sup>1</sup>

```
:argdo %y | %s/old1/new1/g | $pu | %s/old2/new2/g
```

There's also a good chance that you might want to operate on exclusive ranges (do the first substitution only on the first part, and the second only on the second):

```
:argdo $mark a | %co$ | 1,'a s/old1/new1/g | 'a,$s/old2/new2/g
```

To allow non-matching substitutions, add `s///e` and add `silent!` to make operation much faster in the case of many files.

```
:silent! argdo $mark a | %co$ | 1,'a s/old1/new1/ge | 'a,$s/old2/new2/ge
```

---

<sup>1</sup> (*note that argdo expects an Ex command list by default. You'd use e.g. `argdo norm! ggyG` to use normal mode commands*)

Comment: That's great! It's working
I just added |w to the 1st command
:argdo %y | %s/old1/new1/g | $pu | %s/old2/new2/g | w

Comment: @Pansy. That's right. Good call. I always have `:se autowrite autoread` enabled (I have persistent undo and version control for the rest anyways)

Comment: In case of the requirement to run each of the two substitutions only on one copy of original text, one can avoid setting a mark manually: `:argdo %y|%s/o1/n1/g|$pu|'[,$s/o2/n2/g`.

Comment: @ib wow, I knew it. Thanks ib, you've helped the OP, and polished my trade too. I'll upvote you're comment for it :) Somehow, I like the expressiveness of `:%copy $` too, though

Comment: @Pansy:  Consider also using `:update` (`:up`, for short) instead of `:write`.  Unlike the latter, the former does not write a buffer if it has not been modified.

Comment: @sehe: For the case of solution built around the `:copy` command, there is an implementation that does not require setting a mark by hand as well: `:argdo %t0|1,s/o1/n1/g|''+,$s/o2/n2/g`.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD:** my Vim-fu is not as strong as @ib's or @sehe's ones, so you might want to use the solutions they suggested instead of mine one.

But, my solution is easier to edit and to debug personally for me (as a Vim apprentice), so, let it be here anyway.

---

You can add the following temporary function in your `vimrc`:

```
function! MyTmpFunc()
   :%y
   :%s/old1/new1/g
   normal! G
   normal! P
   :%s/old2/new2/g
endfunction
```

Then restart Vim with the files you need to affect (something like `vim myfile1.txt myfile2.txt myfile3.txt`), and execute the following command:

`:argdo call MyTmpFunc()`

That's what you described in your question: function `MyTmpFunc()` will be called for each argument given to Vim.

Now you can delete `MyTmpFunc()` from vimrc.

Be also aware with `:bufdo` - it calls some command for each opened buffer. There is also `:windo`, which executes command for each window, but personally I found `:bufdo` the most useful.

Also please note that you don't have to create temporary function if you need to execute just a single command in the each buffer. Say, if you need just to replace "`old1`" to "`new1`" in the each buffer, then you can execute the following command:

`:bufdo %s/old1/new1/g`

and that's it.

Comment: One does not have to create temporary function to execute several Ex commands: `:argdo %y|%s/o1/n1/g|$pu|%s/o2/n2/g`.

Comment: @ib as always ib, that deserved to be an answer. I added some more ideas in mine

Comment: @ib. yeah, my Vim-fu is not so strong, my bad. But, the way I suggested is easier to edit and to debug personally for me (as a Vim apprentice), so, let it be here anyway. (I updated my answer too)

Comment: This answer deserves every credit it gets, no problem. On the other hand, a function is precisely the same: a list of Ex commands, so I don't see the difference, really. Use `qQ` for [Ex-mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Ex-mode) if you prefer.

Comment: One more hint: use `source $MYVIMRC` to reload your vimrc, and use `:args myfile?.txt` to set the argument list without restarting